# How can I get the range used in generating random number?

Tags: java, random, formula, reverse-engineering, random-seed

I generate random numbers, using a seed in Java. Knowing the final output is 235 and the seed number 532, how can I get the intBound number in java?
e.g

```
int randomNumber
int seed=532;
int intBound=800;
Random rand = Random(seed); 
randomNumber=rand.nextInt(intBound);

System.out.println("The generated Random number using the above seed and int bound is:- "+randomNumber);
//Results is: The generated Random number using the above seed and int bound is: 235
```

A simplified math version of the question is: Knowing only two values of a mathematical formula how do you produce the third value? e.g 1+2=3 which also means if we only know 2 values and the formula used, we can easily get the third value knowing the formula used in getting the result.

Comment: Why do you think this is even possible?

Comment: @user2357112 it could be possible. [See here Random.java](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Random.java) "If two instances of {@code Random} are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers."

Comment: @flakes: None of that would imply that you can recover the upper bound to a `nextInt` call.

Comment: @user2357112 But its interesting in that you can reduce the set of possible values. With a few more calls to `nextInt` at the same bound could limit the set to 1

Comment: @user2357112 I created a small demo to demonstrate! See my answer

Comment: Just curious: if you _could_ do this (which you can't), why would you _want_ to do it?  Who would benefit, and how?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Many upper bounds can produce the same output. For example, a [quick test](https://ideone.com/NVzupX) on Ideone shows 9 possible bounds under 1000000 that would produce an output of 235 with seed 532 (and 800 is not one of them): 237, 369, 711, 3239, 9717, 29151, 50549, 151647, and 454941.

```
import java.util.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<Integer> bounds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
            Random rng = new Random(532);
            if (rng.nextInt(i) == 235) {
                bounds.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(bounds);
    }
}
```

---

The best you can do is determine possible bounds. The implementation of `nextInt(int)` is [required](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) to be equivalent to

```
 public int nextInt(int bound) {
   if (bound <= 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("bound must be positive");

   if ((bound & -bound) == bound)  // i.e., bound is a power of 2
     return (int)((bound * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

   int bits, val;
   do {
       bits = next(31);
       val = bits % bound;
   } while (bits - val + (bound-1) < 0);
   return val;
 }
```

The ways for this algorithm to give a particular output can be divided into three possibilities:

- `bound` is a power of two
- `bound` is not a power of two, and the loop terminates on the first iteration
- `bound` is not a power of two, and the loop continues past the first iteration

The power-of-two `bound` cases are easy - just try every power-of-two `bound` that fits in an `int`. There are only 31 of them. You can optimize this, but there's not much point.

The first-iteration non-power-of-two cases can be handled by computing the value that `next(31)` would have been (which can be done by seeding a `Random` instance and calling `next(31)`), and seeing what values of `bound` would both give the right value of `val` and terminate the do-while.

To give the right value of `val`, `bound` must be a factor of `bits - val` greater than `val`. (Sometimes `bits - val` will be 0, and any integer greater than `val` will pass.) To terminate the do-while, `bits - val + (bound-1)` must not overflow. Thus, the possible bounds that fall into this case are factors of `bits - val` within a certain range, that are not powers of two.

As for the final case, I don't feel like going through it, so that'll be "left as an exercise for the reader". (It's the hardest case, with difficulties like figuring out what values of `bound` would cause an overflow when you don't know `val`, and that'd take more time than I have.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an experimental method for finding the hidden bound. Get a copy of the random object and record outputs from it. Create `n` instances of `Random` where `n` is max int. For each of these `Random` instances use their index as the parameter for `nextInt`. Store only the `Random` instances which adhere to the original sequence. Continue eliminating candidates until only one remains.

Consider the following table. Up top we title the columns with the iteration in which a random value is sampled. On the side we have sequences with the same seed, which have different bound values applied. The values in the middle cells state the random value retrieved for a given Random instance and iteration.

After the first pass through all possible integers we are left with 4 possible candidates. We keep comparing against the authority until only one possible candidate remains. If you do not provide enough samples from the authority it is possible you may be left with multiple matching candidates for the upper bound value.

[image]

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the seed number: ");
    final long seed = scanner.nextLong();
    System.out.print("Please enter the hidden bound: ");
    final int bound = scanner.nextInt();

    final long start = System.nanoTime();

    final IntSupplier original = rand(seed, bound);
    final int firstRandom = original.getAsInt();

    Map<Integer, IntSupplier> candidates = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        final IntSupplier candidate = rand(seed, i);
        if (firstRandom == candidate.getAsInt()) {
            candidates.put(i, candidate);
        }
    }

    int iterations = 1;
    while (candidates.size() > 1) {
        iterations += 1;
        final int current = original.getAsInt();

        Map<Integer, IntSupplier> survivors = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, IntSupplier> entry : candidates.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().getAsInt() == current) {
                survivors.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        candidates = survivors;
    }

    if (candidates.size() == 1) {
        System.out.println("Upper bound is " + candidates.keySet().iterator().next());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No upper bound found");
    }
    System.out.println("Completed in " + iterations +  " iterations");

    final long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Completed in " + (end - start) / Math.pow(10,9) + "seconds");
}

static IntSupplier rand(long seed, int bound) {
    final Random rand = new Random(seed);
    return () -> rand.nextInt(bound);
}
```

This produces the output:

```
Please enter the seed number: 532
Please enter the hidden bound: 800
Upper bound is 800
Completed in 4 iterations
Completed in 46.778499624 seconds
```

Comment: If you can generate as many `randInt` return values as you want and you can afford to crunch numbers for most of a minute, this is an option. With only one `randInt` return value, as in the question, this won't work.

Comment: Also of note is that depending on the bound, especially if it's a very large bound, this could take a lot of `randInt` return values. If you don't have the power to generate them at will (and you're relying on an external source or on pre-recorded outputs), you may end up limited by your supply of `randInt` outputs.